# Dynamic Select Menu in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement a Dynamic Select Menu in my Rails Application, following a youtube video #88  .

I set everything like the video, but my JavaScript doesn't work as it should.

My View code: _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :cliente_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :cliente_id, Cliente.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :projeto_id %><br>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :projeto_id, Cliente.order(:name), :projetos, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

relatos.coffe ->

```
JQuery -> 
  projetos = $('#relato_projeto_id').html()
  $('#relato_cliente_id').change ->
    cliente = $('#relato_cliente_id :selected').text()
    options = $(projetos).filter("optgroup[label='#{cliente}']").html()
    if options 
      $('#relato_projeto_id').html(options)
    else
      $('#relato_projeto_id').empty()
```

The page seems ok, no errors, but when I list the Cliente(Client) it should list only Projects listed to him, but it keeps showing all projects as there is no jquery at all.

Comment: please confirm the extension of js file is ".coffee" not ".coffe"

Comment: Post the generated HTML as opposed to rails as it doesn't help.

Comment: CoffeeScript is indentation-sensitive. What you've given is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Have you tried to raise an alert or show something on the console with `console.log 'something'`?

Comment: Make sure you're watching `log/development.log` to see what parameters are coming in and what queries are being run.

Comment: Kartik - extension is confirmed, renamed to .js.coffee and still didn't work, no errors in page. 
LShetty - Please, could you explain what it means, 
D-side - Can you post an example ? I'm relative new at RoR

Comment: Found ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined in console

Answer (score 0):

The starting of the Code was JQuery when it should be jQuery. Thanks for the person who said it before, but now I see.